# Wordpress: batch convert escaped code in visual editor to HTML?

Tags: html, mysql, wordpress, csv

We are in the process of exporting data from a mysql database (exported as CSV via phpMyAdmin) and importing it as a CSV into Wordpress.

Each post has a large amount of escaped HTML text.

For example, we have:

`&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Example&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;`

instead of:

`<p><strong>Example</strong></p>`

Is there any way to batch convert these items so that the HTML is rendered properly?

Answer (score 0):

filter the exported file through unhtml.
example:

```
$> echo '&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Example&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;' | unhtml

<p><strong>Example</strong></p>
```

qed